# Integrating ads in a QT application

Tags: qt, ads, adsense

I have written a small application in whick i plan to integrate ads (eg. adsense).

One way is to have a QWebView item which will display the ad in the application window.
Can you suggest another way? Do i have to own a website to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can you suggest another way?

That's the only way.

> Do i have to own a website to do this?

No, just display the adsense code inside the QWebView.